# Pandas dataframe row counts to plt incrementally after every 4 consecutive rows

Tags: python

I am trying to assign as ID to a pandas dataframe based on row count. For this I am trying to `apply` the below logic to pandas dataframe:

```
num = df.shape[0]
for i in range(num):
   print(math.ceil(i/4))
```

So the idea is that for every 4 consecutive rows, an ID would be assigned. So the resultant dataframe would look like

```
  col_1    Group_ID
   v_1        1
   v_2        1
   v_3        1
   v_4        1
   v_5        2
   v_6        2
   v_7        2
   v_8        2
   v_9        3
   v_10       3

--- And so on.
```

Just a quick thought. How can I use apply function on `df.index`.
Can I use the below code?

```
df['Index'] = df.index
df[GroupID] = df['Index].apply(np.ceil)
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to `apply`, so create a named function and pass it

```py
def everyFour(rowIdx):
    return math.ceil(rowIdx / 4)

df['GroupId'] = df['Index'].apply(everyFour)
```

or just use a `lambda`

```py
df['GroupId'] = df['Index'].apply(lambda rowIdx: math.ceil(rowIdx / 4))
```

Note that this will leave the first row with index 0 at 0, so you might want to add 1 to the rowIndex before dividing by 4.